# OpenCV - Cropping image after performing deskew

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, crop

In the code below, **points** contain center value of 12 rectangles which creates one rectangle. From this rectangle angle, image is to be deskewed. After deskewing, how can I crop the obtained image?

```
pnts = np.array(points)
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(pnts)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(resized,[box],0,(0,255,0),2)

root_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(rect[0], angle , 1)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(resized, root_mat, dim, flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.getRectSubPix(rotated, dim, center)
```

Comment: To crop an image in OpenCV use this: `cropped = rotated[70:170, 440:540]`. Now display `cropped` using `cv2.imshow()`.

Comment: Also visit [THIS PAGE](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/01/20/basic-image-manipulations-in-python-and-opencv-resizing-scaling-rotating-and-cropping/) for more detailed example on cropping and other image manipulation operations

Comment: @Jeru Luke    cv2.getRectSubPix(rotated, dim, center) what is the use of this function? I sit necessary for deskew of image? Once i rotated image, from bounding box i want to crop image.